# Variable as argument to Wine

Tags: command-line, bash, notepad++, bash-scripting, wine

The variable *$INPUT_FILES* in **Case 1** has the same content (string) that is used in **Case 2**. Why in **Case 1** I have problems with spaces in the name "2015 01 09.1.txt", but in **Case 2** not? How can I fix this?

- Case 1

```
env WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" wine "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe" -multiInst $INPUT_FILES
```

- Case 2

```
env WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" wine "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe" -multiInst Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\camilo.20150407.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\PyVersions.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\20141115.1\\targa_tool_v30\\Readme.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\2015\ 01\ 09.1.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\20150319.1.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\20150514.1.txt Z:\\home\\eduardo\\Desktop\\DESK_TO_CLEAN\\20150109.1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eval as a strategy to get pass the arguments to the Wine/Notepad++!

```
eval "env WINEPREFIX=\"$HOME/.wine\" wine \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe\" -multiInst $INPUT_FILES"
```