# Launch program with Wine using .exe arguments

Tags: command-line, wine

I have this program that I'm able to launch via command prompt in Windows or via a crafted .lnk when adding the specified arguments like this:

```
"C:\My\program.exe" /ID:"MyID" /CompanyID:"123" /TheAddr:"my.address.com"
```

By reading [the documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Passing_Windows_command-line_arguments) it seems that Wine interprets the arguments in the same way Windows does, and even when I'm certain that it is true for arguments presented in this way:

```
wine program.exe -my -arguments
```

It is not working for those arguments described above, maybe I'm missing some sort of escaping for some characters?

I've tried launching the application in this way:

```
wine program.exe /ID:"MyID" /CompanyID:"12" /TheAddr:"my.address.com"
```

But didn't worked, all I got was a generic error message from my program.

I believe that it is because I'm not passing the arguments the correct way, because if I craft a .lnk file in Windows updating its locations to match my Wine's prefix installation and then navigate to it via Wine's explorer.exe and double click on it, my program runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
exec wine "~/.wine/drive_c/My/program.exe" "-my"
```

- The exec commands tell bash to morph into wine with the following arguments, so this is no longer bash running wine, but bash process becoming wine. The PID remains. You don't have two processes running.

The solution given to this question  can be found on Unix.SE.

[Transparently run wine programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70681/transparently-run-wine-programs)

Comment: This didn’t work for me. But https://superuser.com/a/935481/180675 did. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use:
sudo wine start cmd

For more information use this website: https://wiki.winehq.org/List_of_Commands

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1225577)