# How to add .exe switches/parameters in Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, wine, avi, parameters

In windows, it's simple

```
"c:\path\to\exe\program.exe" -option1 -option2
```

I'm installing and running games through Lutris to make using WINE for gaming easier. I'm trying to play SWAT 3. However, the .avi videos won't work on modern systems because the codec is ancient and has never been updated. I've tried a few things that *should* have worked. However, the game keeps crashing at the intro video. I want to at least skip the intro video to see if I've got different problems to worry about. In windows, I'd make a shortcut to the .exe and add `-nointro` to the target and be done. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do the same thing in Linux and I apparently don't know the right thing to google to find the answer.

Linux Mint 19.x;
Lutris 0.5.7.1;
WINE 5.0.3;

Comment: Hi, this could be helpful: [Launch program with Wine using .exe arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/1058985/launch-program-with-wine-using-exe-arguments)